# MPMoviePlayerController Auto-rotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using an `MPMoviePlayerController` in my app. I am not presenting it as a view controller but adding its `view` to my own view controller. The video plays just fine and I can go fullscreen.

However, because on the whole my app only supports portrait orientations when I go fullscreen when watching my video I can't rotate.

So, how can I have it so that when my `MPMoviePlayerController` goes into fullscreen have it auto rotate (support both landscape and portrait) but then when outside of fullscreen mode, be kept in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because on the whole my app only supports portrait orientations

But there's your answer right there. On iOS 6, whatever your app as a whole does (as given in the Info.plist settings) is the whole of what your app can do. If your app as a whole does not support landscape, then no view controller in your app can support landscape.

Let's say the app supports all orientations. Then each view controller that does *not* support all orientations can say "No, I just support portrait orientation" in its `supportedInterfaceOrientations` implementation.

But this controller won't say that, so it will rotate.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to extend MPMoviePlayerViewController's class? So your class can respond to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation's method.

Comment: Do not confuse MPMoviePlayerViewController with MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: I'm not confusing classes, it's only a suggest. Extends MPMoviePlayerController and use that sounds a better practice in this case.

Comment: But he already said that he was using MPMoviePlayerController to show the movie in a view within his view controller. So that's a given. Now the problem is that the user can enlarge this to full screen. If he wanted to present the movie initially with MPMoviePlayerViewController, presumably he'd be doing that to start with.